# Is it possible to edit schema and db name of org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, testcontainers

I'm using TestContainers' `PostgreSQLContainer` to test a Spring application, and I want to configure the DB to have a specific schema and DB name. The defaults are db_name=`test` and schema=`public`.

Is it possible to edit those? Of so, where and how?

I've an `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

My PostgreSQLContainer implementation of the `start()` method:

```
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
public class DefaultPostgresContainer extends PostgreSQLContainer<DefaultPostgresContainer> {



private static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "postgres:13";
private static DefaultPostgresContainer container;

private DefaultPostgresContainer() {
        super(IMAGE_VERSION);
}

public static DefaultPostgresContainer getInstance() {
    if (container == null) {
        container = new DefaultPostgresContainer().withInitScript("init_postgresql.sql");
    }
    return container;
}

@Override
public void start() {
    super.start();
    System.setProperty("DB_URL", container.getJdbcUrl());
    System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", "my_test");
    System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", "my_test");
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    //do nothing, JVM handles shutdown
}
}
```

Comment: You can configure the database name with [`withDatabaseName`](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/modules/postgresql/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/PostgreSQLContainer.java#L111). Schemas are a PostgreSQL concern, not a testcontainers concern, so you need to solve that just like you would with a "normal" db.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in the comments, the `withDatabaseName()` method will provide you with a way so set a name different from the default value. So in your case you could simple do the following:

```java
public static DefaultPostgresContainer getInstance() {
    if (container == null) {
        container = new DefaultPostgresContainer()
                             .withInitScript("init_postgresql.sql")
                             .withDatabaseName("mydatabase");
    }
    return container;
}
```

The hint on working with schemas was also already given in the comments: custom schemas can easily be managed via JDBC (you'd have to create it before using it).

To select a custom schema as "default" in a JDBC connection to a `PostgreSQLContainer` you can do the following:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", psqlContainer.getUsername());
properties.setProperty("password", psqlContainer.getPassword());
properties.setProperty("currentSchema", SCHEMA_NAME);    // this sets the "default" schema for queries
final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(psqlContainer.getJdbcUrl(), properties);
```

If you want to see it in action I've put together [some simple test cases](https://github.com/dajudge/testcontainers-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/com/dajudge/testcontainers/examples/PostgreSQLTests.java) demonstrating the mechanisms explained here.